# Search and replace html tags in sed recursively

Tags: html, search, sed

I am trying to write a script to search and remove htm and html tags from all files recursively. The starting point is given as input in the command to run the script. The resultant files should be saved in new file at the same place ending with _changed. e.g., start.html > start.html_changed.
Here is the script I wrote so far. It works fine, but the output prints out to the terminal, and I want it to be saved in files respectively.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo find $1 -name '*.html' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -n '/<div/,/<\/div>/p'

sudo find $1 -name '*.htm' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -n '/<div/,/<\/div>/p'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

The following script works just fine, but it is not recursive. how can I make it recursive?

```
#!/bin/bash

for l in /$1/*.html
 do
   sed -n '/<div/,/<\/div>/p' $l > "${l}_nobody"
 done

for m in /$1/*.htm
 do
   sed -n '/<div/,/<\/div>/p' $m > "${m}_nobody"
 done
```

Comment: html could be very complex so not easy with a simple sed. Use a xml parser for this. (ex of problem: what about the behavior on a pattern `</div>` inside a text in a div section ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the `xargs` part as follows:

```
xargs -0 -I {} sh -c "sed -n '/<div/,/<\/div>/p' {} > {}_changed"
```

**Explanation:**

- `-I {}`: sets a placeholder
- `> {}_changed"`: does redirection to the file with `_changed` suffix

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked nicely, but you forgot the -n after sed, otherwise it will just add the required lines into the newly created file, without removing the original text.

Comment: works only if `<div` and `</div>` are on different lines and no  'false' div tag inside content.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu whats a 'false' div tag ?

Comment: the string `<div` or `</div` inside the tag section itself (ex `<div><textarea>sample of <div here:</textarea></div>`). Sed is litteraly read the input, not like a parser so you need to manage those kind of pleasure unless you are sur there is only simple same strutctured html (like: always or never div tag on the same line, ...)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, how would the command be is you have 'false' div tag inside content? I need to write a script to deal with that version as well.

Comment: I often hide the false sequence with a temporary substituion before the main work, and put them back after. Something that working with a parser don't need to be done. An idea of substitution is something like `:a;s/\(\("[^"]*"[^"]*\)*"[^"]*\)<div\([^"]*"\)/\1__FALSE_DIV__\2/;ta`